Is there any evidence that culture has gotten more “sensitive” or “politically correct”?
This question might be more suitable for History SE, I’m not sure.
I have heard people pretty regularly claim that “nowadays” “political correctness” is more of a big thing - even that people are more “sensitive”, more “intolerant” of different viewpoints.
On the one hand, I have considered that social taboos and stigmas are obviously nothing new, even though what they are specifically about changes.
On the other hand, it’s not an invalid idea that different cultures, societies, social groups, and periods of history do have different social dynamics. People can be extremely impressionable, and it is very, very human to need to adapt to your social environment to not be ostracized.
I sometimes have had this impression when I meet someone from a foreign culture who is simply unaware of certain cultural dynamics in my culture. It’s interesting to think that they have no idea how “touchy” something they have said has gotten. It makes me think about how relentless amounts of social pressure and animosity slowly mold even the resistant amongst us to have to conform, even if via repression. Those who are fluent in a cultural code can only violate it in an extremely reactionistic and self-aware way. This is completely different from someone who never got exposed to certain cultural taboos in the first place.
I’m just curious if there’s a way to assess the claim that people are “more sensitive” nowadays. Are they? Fifty years ago, say - was there a “similar level” of social friction, just about other things; or is there some quasi-measurable way to show that nowadays, it is more common to be vocally angry when, say, you disagree on particular social or political values?
There might be some connection between what I wrote and Freud and/or anthropologists like Levi-Strauss, but I’m open to anything.

It's undeniable that there are recent movements to be more considerate towards minority groups, to grant them equal rights, and to reduce discrimination and hate against them. Similar to how people fought for the rights of women and people of colour in the past. Although people disagree on whether this is a good or a bad thing (although few would just outright say we should be inconsiderate, discriminatory and/or hateful - they usually try to offer some poor justification for those things). And there are certainly also people pushing in the opposite direction.

I upvoted because the question of whether a metric exists to measure political correctness is certainly a political philosophy and philosophy of sociology/culture question; political narratives are entirely a fascinating question. Philosophically, this might be related to Progress. Consider https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/progress/ and https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/critical-theory/.

I think fundamentally humans are constantly searching for optimised quality of life improvements. Where once quality of life improvements came in the form of immediate needs being met, we're now at a paradigm shift where mental, emotional and identitative needs are being focused on as the immediate needs are  generally more plentiful.
